# Testing sub application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a base admin controller that inherits from `ApplicationController`. In order to test a before filter in `Admin::BaseController`, I created an anonymous controller in this spec.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::BaseController do

  it { should be_a(ApplicationController) }

  controller do
    def index
      render :text => ''
    end
  end

  context 'when current user is not an admin' do
    it 'redirects to root path' do
      get :index
      response.should redirect_to(root_path)
    end
  end
end
```

But when I make a request for `index` action, it doesn't call the before filter in `Admin::BaseController`.

When I define that filter in `ApplicationController` instead of `Admin::BaseController` and run the test, it works. Apparently this anonymous controller inherits from `ApplicationController`. How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer here; https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller

```
controller(Admin::BaseController) do
  def index
    render :text => ''
  end
end
```

did the trick.